# Trying to Full Join two tables in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I was trying to full join to tables as the code below,

```
SELECT C.cust_name,O.ord_num
FROM customers C
  FULL JOIN orders O
  ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code;
```

but this code is not working.Is anyone can solve this?

Comment: Why would you need a `full join` for this? Isn't each order related to one and and only one customer?

Comment: use full outer join

Comment: @GMB no there are 33 customers in the customers table

Comment: @Shadiqur same syntax error is appeared

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result ([mcve]).

Comment: Hey, not as a comment (too hard to read), edit the question instead.

Comment: `mysql> select cust_name from customers;
+-------------+
| cust_name   |
+-------------+
| Micheal     |
| Bolt        |
| Martin      |
| Winston     |
| Sasikant    |
| Shilton     |
| Ramanathan  |
| Karolina    |
| Ramesh      |
| Charles     |
| Sundariya   |
| Steven      |
| Holmes      |
| Rangarappa  |
| Stuart      |
| Venkatpati  |
| Srinivas    |
| Fleming     |
| Yearannaidu |
| Albert      |
| Jacks       |
| Avinash     |
| Karl        |
| Cook        |
| Ravindran   |
+-------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT C.cust_name, O.ord_num
FROM customers C
LEFT JOIN orders O
  ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code
UNION ALL
SELECT null, O.ord_num
FROM orders O
LEFT JOIN customers C
  ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code
WHERE C.cust_code IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

FULL OUTER JOIN result without FULL OUTER JOIN support:

```
SELECT C.cust_name,O.ord_num
FROM customers C
  LEFT JOIN orders O
  ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, O.ord_num
FROM orders O
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from customers C where C.cust_code = O.cust_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` & `LEFT JOIN` will be equivalent :

```
SELECT C.cust_name, O.ord_num
FROM customers C LEFT JOIN
     orders O
     ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code
UNION ALL -- Use UNION if you don't want duplicate
SELECT C.cust_name, O.ord_num
FROM orders O LEFT JOIN
     customers C
     ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code;
```

Comment: Will return duplicates for the matching rows.

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.cust_code' at line 8` this error was shown up

Answer (score 0):

You are using Full Join in your Query, Correct Query will be:

```
    SELECT C.cust_name,O.ord_num
    FROM customers C
    FULL OUTER JOIN orders O
    ON C.cust_code = O.cust_code;
```

There is no such Join **FULL JOIN**, Correct is **FULL OUTER JOIN**

Comment: `FULL JOIN` is the same as `FULL OUTER JOIN`, since the `OUTER` keyword is optional. However, MySQL doesn't support it.